# Converting a Visual Basic.net Listbox control to an ASP.net Listbox Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2012

I am converting a VisualBasic program written in Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2013 for Web using Visual Basic.  I am have difficulty with the ListView control.

My VB.net code is:

```
    Dim itm As ListViewItem
      For i = 0 To UBound(temporder, 1)
         If temporder(i, 1) <> "no-data" Then
            itm = Edit_Composition.ToListBox.Items.Add(temporder(i, 1))
            itm.SubItems.Add(temporder(i, 0))
         End If
   Next i
```

In general, what I am doing is building a list (ToListBox) from user selected items in another list (FromListBox).  The ToListBox has two columns and the first column can be edited by the user during run time.  The FromList is created and loaded in the Page load event.  Also, if the user has save a previous session, the TolistBox is populated from an array(temporder) of saved values on the page load event.

When I paste this code into my VS for Web I the error: 'value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListviewDataItem'.

A previous post on a similar issue in C#, said that initializing statement is wrong.  I am at a loss on what is the correct initializing statement.

Can you help me to solve my issue?

Thanks, John W

More background on what I am trying to accomplish in ASP.NET:

I have already created a visual basic program that includes a function to build a list based on user selections for another list.

I am trying to accomplish the same functionality in ASP.NET.

Before I launch into more code development, I am asking for some recommendations on the best way to proceed in ASP.NET.

The functionality allows the user to select an item from the list on the left and add it to the list on the right.  The list on the right has two columns the first column with the number (100 in the image) needs to be edited by the user.  The second column is not edited by the user.  As the user adds more and more items from the left, the user must edit the first column on the right so that the total of all of the first columns is equal to 100.

My initial thoughts were to use a listview or gridview for the right side list, but after some research I am thinking of a table and adding a row for each item selected on the left.  In the row, add a text box and a label.

Any thoughts of the direction I should explore before developing any more code would be appreciated.

Thanks again,

John W.

Comment: My suggestion is - do not try to convert. This will take you more time, than creating it fresh and clean in asp.net.

Comment: Roger that.  I have added a bit more background in my initial question, and the direction I am thinking of exploring.  I am thinking of a table and adding a text-box and label for each row during run-time.